# Standard Installation Locations for git repositories (e.g. jQuery)

Tags: git

I've found a few different answers, and was curious if there is a standard between it being in a folder under $HOME or something like /var?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No standard but if a repo then it is only writeable by you so under $HOME

If it is on a server and no access except by http or git protocols then anywhere (and some setups might use var I would use /git)